# Embed javascript in pdf with pdfkit

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, node-pdfkit

Is that possible to embed some javascript code into the pdf file that I'm creating using NodeJS PDFKit (http://pdfkit.org/)?

I know how to embed javascript with C# using PDFSharp, and when i look into the two files created by PDFSharp, one with embedded javascript, and one without they have the following differences:

**The one with javascript containts to additional objects that are inserted as the last to objects:**

```
30 0 obj
<<
/S/JavaScript
/JS(this.print\(true\); )
>>
endobj
31 0 obj
<<
/Names[(EmbeddedJS)30 0 R]
>>
endobj
```

In this case the js i'm embedding is `this.print\(true\);`. Also after that the object reference offsets are different accordingly.

And there is also this:

```
/Names
<<
/JavaScript 31 0 R
>>
```

reference in the second object of the pdf. This whole object looks like this:

```
2 0 obj
<<
/Type/Catalog
/Pages 3 0 R
/Names
<<
/JavaScript 31 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
```

And when I try to insert this code into a pdf generated by pdfkit i get a corrupted file. Is there something I'm missing? Is there possibly a better way to embed javascript into pdf with pdfkit?

PS. Of course I calculate the proper object numbers, adjust the offsets etc.

Answer (score 0):

I saw more direct way of embedding JS than the one done by PDFSharp:
http://bililite.com/blog/2012/06/06/adding-javascript-to-pdf-files/

It looks like this:

```
0 1 obj
<< 
  /Type /Catalog
  /Pages 0 2 R % a standard catalog entry
  /Names << % the Javascript entry
    /JavaScript <<
      /Names [
        (EmbeddedJS)
        <<
          /S /JavaScript
          /JS (
            app.alert('Hello, World!');
          )
        >>
      ]
    >>
  >> % end of the javascript entry
>>
endobj
```

I went ahead and implemented a hacky way as a proof of concept:

```
const originalToString = Object.prototype.toString;
Object.prototype.toString = function() {
  if (this.hasOwnProperty('rawForPdfKit')) {
    return 'hey, pdfkit, this is totally not an object, we pinky promise, please fall back to raw concatenation';
  }
  return originalToString.call(this);
};

function generatePdf() {
  const Raw = (function () {
    function Raw(rawData) {
      this.rawData = rawData;
      this.rawForPdfKit = true;
    }
    Raw.prototype.toString = function () {
      return this.rawData;
    };
    return Raw;
  }());

  const doc = new PdfDocument();
  const raw = new Raw(`<<
    /JavaScript <<
      /Names [
        (EmbeddedJS)
        <<
          /S /JavaScript
          /JS (
            this.print();
          )
        >>
      ]
    >>
  >>`);

  doc['_root'].data.Names = raw;

  ...
}
```

Obligatory warning:
This method relies on PDFKit's private APIs and implementation details, so this might break anything anytime with PDFKit upgrades.

Comment: There is a cleaner implementation here, but I haven't been able to get it work in my codebase: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/0.1.18/src/printer.js#L107

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to autotrigger print without JavaScript:

```
var ref = doc.ref({
  Type: 'Action',
  S: 'Named',
  N: 'Print'
});

doc._root.data.OpenAction = ref;
ref.end();
```

From: https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/217#issuecomment-39281561